# PHP Ajax not responding

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In the username availability check I created two pages: *register.php* and *registercontrol.php* controlling it. I check the database connection its on work. Everything (all statements, insertin data into db) that was previously created on a single php page. But when ajax validates other inputs its duplicates the html content and shows the error inside of it instead of showing error messages in a just single html element.

So I seperated it into two pages but now ajax not shows any error and responds. Here is my work:

registercontrol.php

```
<?php

require('../includes/config.php');


if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if (! $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        $infoun[] = 'Your username must be at least 6 alphanumeric characters';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (! empty($row['username'])){
            $errorun[] = 'This username already in use';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

register.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("#username").keyup(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $(this).val().trim();
        if(username.length >= 3){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'registercontrol.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {username:username},
                success: function(response){
                // Show response
                $("#uname_response").html(response);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("#uname_response").html("");
        }

        });     

    });
</script>

<form id="register-form" class="user" role="form" method="post" action="registercontrol.php" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control form-control-user" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES); } ?>" tabindex="2" required>

<div id="uname_response" ></div>

</form>
```

Comment: Where do you define the $user object in file registercontrol.php? Also attach your config.php please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to print the response in registercontrol.php so that we can get response in your register.php

Change your code as below

```
<?php

require('../includes/config.php');


if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if (! $user->isValidUsername($username)){
       echo 'Your username must be at least 6 alphanumeric characters';
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (! empty($row['username'])){
            echo 'This username already in use';
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return or echo something from registercontrol.php

```
<?php

require('../includes/config.php');


if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    //username validation
    $username = $_POST['username'];

    if (! $user->isValidUsername($username)){
        $infoun[] = 'Your username must be at least 6 alphanumeric characters';
    echo json_encode($infoun);
    exit;
       
    } else {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (! empty($row['username'])){
            $errorun[] = 'This username already in use';
            echo json_encode($errorun);
            exit;
        }
        echo $row[username];
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```